# Retries in dask.compute() are unclear

Tags: dask, dask-delayed

From the documentation, `Number of allowed automatic retries if computing a result fails.`

Does "result" refer to each individual task or the entire compute() call?

If it refers to the entire call, how to implement retries for each task in dask.delayed?

Also, I'm not sure if the retries are working at all, as per below code.

```py
import dask
import random

@dask.delayed
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@dask.delayed
def divide(sum_i):
    n = random.randint(0, 1)
    result = sum_i / n
    return result

tasks = []
for i in range(3):
    sum_i = add(i, i+1)
    divide_n = divide(sum_i)
    tasks.append(divide_n)

dask.compute(*tasks, retries=1000)
```

Expected output is (1, 3, 5), actual is ZeroDivisionError.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is interested, we use a @retry decorator for tasks, like so:

```py
@dask.delayed
@retry(Exception, tries=3, delay=5)
def my_func():
    pass
```

Retry decorator:

```py
from functools import wraps

def retry(exceptions, tries=4, delay=3, backoff=2, logger=None):
    """
    Retry calling the decorated function using an exponential backoff.

    Args:
        exceptions: The exception to check. may be a tuple of
            exceptions to check.
        tries: Number of times to try (not retry) before giving up.
        delay: Initial delay between retries in seconds.
        backoff: Backoff multiplier (e.g. value of 2 will double the delay
            each retry).
        logger: Logger to use.

    """
    if not logger:
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    def deco_retry(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def f_retry(*args, **kwargs):
            mtries, mdelay = tries, delay
            while mtries > 1:
                try:
                    return f(*args, **kwargs)
                except exceptions as e:
                    msg = f"{e}, \nRetrying in {mdelay} seconds..."
                    logger.warning(msg)
                    sleep(mdelay)
                    mtries -= 1
                    mdelay *= backoff
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return f_retry  # true decorator

    return deco_retry
```

Comment: To clarify, this gets ahead of Dasks internal retry mechanism by catching the exception before it ever makes it all the way up to the worker?

Comment: I don't know what retries does Dask have (they never worked for us), but this is happening inside the task so yes, this would be executed before Dask knows there was any exception.