# How to handle graceful failure in Dask?

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-distributed

I'm running a hour long computation that fetches an external API, process it and save to a dataframe. The API is using Python's request library.

By tweaking the request lib, I managed to fend off problems related to retries and reading errors, but not all possible problems are handled, of course.

Everytime the API fails, my computation just stops, and I lose one hour worth of work.

I'm calling dask like this:

```
dd = daskDataFrame.from_pandas(result, npartitions=20)
future = dd.compute()
```

Is there any way to restart Dask from the point it if failed?

By reading the documentation, there now the Client.retry() function:
https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#distributed.Client.retry

By I don't know how to use it in my code.

Is the retry function the solution? if yes, how to use it?

I also found this correlated question in SO:

[Retries in dask.compute() are unclear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58098598/retries-in-dask-compute-are-unclear)

But I don't know if I need to implement the suggested code in the answer, or just call my compute() function with the retries parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running `.compute` on the dask dataframe you are converting it into a pandas dataframe in memory. If you want a future object, then you can run:

```py
future = client.compute(dd)
# or
future = client.persist(dd)
```

Should one of the above fail, you will see `error` in the `status` property of the future:

```py
print(future.status)
# will print error if the dataframe could not be computed
```

It's not clear what is the best way for your use case, but one option is to have a loop that checks status and if it's an error, then retries/restarts the computation, something like this:

```py
from dask.distributed import wait
while future.status!="finished":
    wait(future)
    if future.status == 'error':
        future.retry()
```

Comment: what is the difference between compute() and persist()?

Comment: in this context, not much of a difference, but in general `persist` allows you to compute an object and make sure it remains in the worker memory (so can also be distributed across multiple workers), see https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#distributed.Client.persist